# To what HTML element can I append all possible HTML elements using innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html, string, innerhtml

I have to pass HTML around in as a string (as I'm using postmessage for communication). To apply modifications to the html, I'm doing:

```
function foo(my_string) {
  var temp, element_list;

  temp = document.createElement("div")
  temp.innerHTML = my_string;
  element_list = temp.querySelectorAll(".foo");
  ...
```

My problem is that `my_string` can be anything and in case I'm passing a string with table rows and cells like this:

```
  '<tr>' +
    '<td>' +
      '<a href="#gadget._key=project_module%2F1&amp;gadget.view=view">' +
        'My Test Project 2014/12/16 14:24:48.930904 GMT' +
      '</a>' +
    '</td>' +
    '...' +
  '</tr>'
```

appending this to a `<div>` removes the table rows and cells and I'm left with links only. Something like this:

```
      '<a href="#gadget._key=project_module%2F1&amp;gadget.view=view">' +
        'My Test Project 2014/12/16 14:24:48.930904 GMT' +
      '</a>' +
```

**Question:**
Is there a generic element, which accepts any type of child elements and does not modify whatever it's passed via innerHTML?

Thanks!

**Edit**:
The method is used to translate html snippets. When I'm updating a table, it will only pass the generated table rows vs receiving the whole table on the initial page rendering.

Comment: Why are you trying to put a TR inside a DIV and not inside a TABLE tag?

Comment: because the method sometimes gets table rows, sometimes divs, sometimes forms. Can be anything.

Comment: why don't you pass some metadata around - or pass the complete table.

Comment: It would be all fine if you passed a whole `<table>` element, otherwise purifying the content will be a hard thing to do cause it's unpredictable.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think there's any good way to force yourself down this path. Maybe you could back the problem out a bit, as this may be an "X/Y problem". and tell us why this method *needs to* (or already does) return random un-fitted HTML. I'm praying this isn't the output of some commonly used library. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: This is the sort of problem that would make me want to step back and contemplate the overall system design.

Comment: @DanielA.White: I have to pass strings only since this is across iframes

Comment: @frequent use a json payload.

Comment: You either change the code that spits stuff out OR you have to sniff the code to see what is being returned.

Comment: @Pointy: True... looking at a lot of file requiring a container element to be set on the postmessage source.

Answer (score 5):

There isn't such an element. `<tr>` is a very good example of this. [According to W3C standards, the "Permitted parent elements" for `<tr>` are "A `<table>`, `<thead>`, `<tbody>` or `<tfoot>` element."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr)

If you *must* have these strings coming in as they are, your best bet is to perform some sort of detection as to the type of element(s) you are inserting, and wrap them in the appropriate HTML if required.

For example: ([View as a CodePen](http://codepen.io/grinn/pen/yyaZXw))

**HTML**

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var anyone = "<div>In a Div</div>";
var tableOnly = "<tr><td>In a..</td></tr>" +
    "<tr><td>...table</td></tr>";

$(function () {
  var $container = $("#container");
  appendContent(anyone);
  appendContent(tableOnly);

  function appendContent(html) {
    var $html = $(html),
        $parent = $(),
        lastParent = "";
    $html.each(function () {
      var parent = parentTag(this.tagName);

      if(parent !== lastParent)
      {
        $container.append($parent);
        $parent = $(parent);
      }
      $parent.append(this);
      lastParent = parent;
    });

    $container.append($parent);
  }

  function parentTag(tagName) {
    switch (tagName.toLowerCase()) {
      case "tr":
        return "<table></table>";
      default:
        return "<div></div>";
    }
  }

});
```

**Edit:** Note that the technique used here to detect the tags used in your HTML can have problems if your HTML contains content that cannot be part of the same parent. For example, the following code would fail:

```
appendContent("<tr><td>Also in a table</td></tr><div>Also in a div</div>");
```

This is because of how jQuery internally builds its selectors. Since you can't have a `div` tag as a sibling to a `tr`, effectively the `div` element gets dropped. [Here's a CodePen demonstrating this](http://codepen.io/grinn/pen/zxKeEx), but from the sound of things, this wouldn't be an issue for the OP's needs. If it is, you could use some alternative method of detecting the tags such as Regular Expressions.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>If you append the mal-formatted HTML data (as you've noticed) with missing tags you're at the Browser DOM parser mercy removing every single one till a conformable HTML is returned.</sub>

**If your main concern (*project-wise*) is just about *table HTML content***  than you could
**treat the string as an `XML` data** structure and get the needed wrapping tag and act accordingly:

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/sivujo/3/edit?html,js,console,output)***

```
function sanitizeHTML( string ) {

  // Treat friendly a HTMLString as XML structure:
  var par = new DOMParser();
  var doc = par.parseFromString(string, 'text/xml');
  var chd = doc.firstChild;
  var tag = chd.nodeName.toUpperCase(); // Get the tag
  var ele;

  function wrapWith(parent, childEl){ // Wrap a node into a parent
    var p = document.createElement(parent);
    p.appendChild(childEl);
    return p;                         // And return that parent element.
  }

  if(/^(THEAD|TBODY|TR)$/.test(tag)){ // If THEAD or TBODY or TR
    ele = wrapWith("table", chd);     // just wrap in TABLE.
  }else if(/^(TD|TH)$/.test(tag)){    // Else if TD or TH
    ele = wrapWith("tr", chd);        // wrap first in TR
    ele = wrapWith("table", ele);     // and than in TABLE.
  }else{
    // All fine. Do we need something here?
  }

  return ele || chd; // Returns a HTMLElement
}

// This will return the final HTMLElement:
// var myEl = sanitizeHTML( str ); 

// Let's see in console:
console.log( sanitizeHTML( str ).outerHTML );
```

For simplicity sake the above code will consider strings with only one children.
To extend it - loop all the children of the `doc` object.

Answer (score -1):

See this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Grezzo/x1qxjx5y/

With `<tr>`s in `<table>`s they are ok.

It's because you are putting a `<tr>` in a `<div>` which isn't valid.

**Putting unsanitized content in the page like this is a real security risk**

Update: I updated the jsfiddle to include two `<div>`s that were not modified by javascript and you can see that the `<tr>`s are stripped if they are not in a `<table>` parent: http://jsfiddle.net/Grezzo/x1qxjx5y/1/

Comment: Grezzo brings up a valid point: The OP gives the impression that he cannot change or control the HTML content returned from the method. That makes me wonder whether the HTML given back can always be trusted not to contain a click-hijacker or something...

Comment: It's not a security risk if the content is being sent with a certified `targetOrigin` and if the OP knows exactly what he's doing.